# Bash file does not run by directory in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, directory

When I run a bash file inside its directory in ubuntu there isn't any problem
But when I try to run it by its directory I get the error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /directory/file.sh
```

Comment: Are you using the correct path for the file? Since `/directory/file.sh` starts with "/", it's treated as an absolute path, meaning it'll look for `directory` at the top level of the startup volume. Is that actually where it is?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the /var/bashfiles/ directory and I use  /var/bashfiles/file.sh to run it

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue.

Comment: The file runs successfully inside directory and the permission is 755

Comment: show us the output of `/bin/ls -ld /var` . It's likely that it, or `bashfiles` doesn't have `the proper `7` or `5` value. Good luck.

Comment: /bin/ls -ld /var
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Dec  3 14:30 /var

Comment: some new facts! I created the sh file by a non root user. There is not any problem in the non root user but for root

Answer (score 0):

I followed this steps:

$ cat web/test.sh

#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/testweb

echo "File has been created succesfully"

$ ls -la web/test.sh
-rwxr--r-- 1 test test 88 Dec  5 05:58 web/test.sh

1- $ date

Sat 05 Dec 2020 06:00:14 AM UTC

2- $ /home/test-env/web/test.sh

File has been created succesfully

3- $ ls -la /tmp/test*

-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 0 Dec  5 06:00 /tmp/testweb

Able to run the file in ubuntu and debian as well